# Как при наличие {8} или {8,9} получить true, но если в тексте кроме {8} и {8,9} присутствуют просто фигурные скобки то false?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулятор выражение чтобы при условие:

Если `#\{[0-9]+\}|\{[0-9]+,[0-9]+\}#` то `True`, но если в тексте кроме `{8}` и `{8,19}` присутствуют обычные фигурные скобки: `{`,`}` или `{}` то `False`.

Как написать регулятор выражение чтобы при таких условиях получить `true` или `false`?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `\{\d+(,\d+)*\}`

Comment: P.S. [Пример в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/6Ljph1gu/)

Comment: \{\d+(,\d+)*\} - не работает. получаю true. А нужно false - {888888,5555} { fgdgdgfd {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача сформулирована так, что в тексте допустимо **только одно** вхождение группы чисел в фигурных скобках `{\d+}|{\d+,\d+}` (далее - Группа) в окружении любых символов, кроме фигурных скобок, то можно использовать выражение `^[^}{]*(?:{\d+}|{\d+,\d+})[^}{]*$`. Здесь начинаем просмотр с начала строки, запрещаем символы фигурных скобок `[^}{]*` до Группы, проверяем Группу, далее до конца строки также запрещаем символы фигурных скобок.

```js
const text = '{8}\n' +
    '{8,9}\n' +
    '{8}{8,9}nlsca\n' +
    '{15}{87,99}{87,99}{2,4}fff\n' +
    '{}\n' +
    '{8}{,}mc;klca\n' +
    '{}{8,9}\n' +
    ' gh ndg dfg{8}{8,9}{,}fbnnhn\n' +
    '{55,45,88}\n' +
    '{55,45,88}{8,9}\n' +
    'ffdsfsfsfaav {55,45} wdjldjasda\n' +
    'lsdlskdlskdls\n' +
    '{55,45}\n' +
    '{55,45}ffdsfsfsfaav'

rg = RegExp('^[^}{]*(?:{\\d+}|{\\d+,\\d+})[^}{]*$')
text.split('\n').forEach(t => console.log(t, rg.test(t)));
```

**Если же таких Групп допустимо несколько**, то можно применить выражение

```
^(?:[^}{]*(?:{\d+}|{\d+,\d+})[^}{]*)+$
```

т.е. оформить подвыражение от ^ до $ как незахватываемую группу и добавить квантификатор +.

```js
const text = '{8}\n' +
    '{8,9}\n' +
    '{8}{8,9}nlsca\n' +
    '{15}{87,99}  {87,99}dddd{2,4}fff\n' +
    '{}\n' +
    '{8}{,}mc;klca\n' +
    '{}{8,9}\n' +
    ' gh ndg dfg{8}{8,9}{,}fbnnhn\n' +
    '{55,45,88}\n' +
    '{55,45,88}{8,9}\n' +
    'ffdsfsfsfaav {55,45} wdjldjasda\n' +
    'lsdlskdlskdls\n' +
    '{55,45}\n' +
    '{55,45}ffdsfsfsfaav'

rg = RegExp('^(?:[^}{]*(?:{\\d+}|{\\d+,\\d+})[^}{]*)+$')
text.split('\n').forEach(t => console.log(t, rg.test(t)));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. /^(?:[^}{]*(?:{\d+}|{\d+,\d+})[^}{]*)+$/ - работает.